# how to check OS system date format using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am using excel 2007, ms visual basic 6.0.
I required to check the window os date format (e.g, whether is it using d/m/yyyy or m/d/yyyy), in order to using the following code.

```
Dim lastdateofmonth As Date
Dim lastwhichday As String
slastdayofmonth = "31"
'if the OS system is using m/d/yyyy then use this
lastdateofmonth = (sTxtMMM + "/" + slastdayofmonth + "/" + TxtYYYY)
lastwhichday = Weekday(lastdateofmonth)
'if th OS system is using d/m/yyyy then use this
lastdateofmonth = (slastdayofmonth+ "/" + sTxtMMM  + "/" + TxtYYYY)
```

anyone can help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Examine **Day(cDate("1/2/14"))**  If its a **1** then you have d/m/yyy.  If its **2** you have m/d/yyy

Answer (score 6):

hmm... i found a better way

```
'========== Check OS Date format========
Dim OSDateFormatType As Integer
'  0 = month-day-year;   1 = day-month-year;   2 = year-month-day
If Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 0 Then
    OSDateFormatType = 0
ElseIf Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 1 Then
    OSDateFormatType = 1
ElseIf Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 2 Then
    OSDateFormatType = 2
End If
```

But this only work for excel.

Comment: A simple `OSDateFormatType = Application.International(xlDateOrder)` would also do :) BTW what do you mean by `But this only work for excel.`? You wanted to do this in Excel only Right?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code....

```
Sub getSystemDateFormat()

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If isSheetExists(ThisWorkbook, "Temp") = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Temp"
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(1, 1) = ""

'On Error GoTo ErrHandle

'Get Date format
lngDateFormat = Application.International(xlDateOrder)
'Get Date Separator
strDateSeparator = Application.International(xlDateSeparator)

'Get leading 0 for day
If Application.International(xlDayLeadingZero) Then
    strDayFormat = "dd"
Else
    strDayFormat = "d"
End If

'Get leading 0 for month
If Application.International(xlMonthLeadingZero) Then
    
    strMonthFormat = "mm"
Else
    strMonthFormat = "m"
End If

'Get 4 digit/2 digit format for year
If Application.International(xl4DigitYears) Then
    strYearFormat = "yyyy"
Else
    strYearFormat = "yy"
End If


'Consolidate the values
If lngDateFormat = 0 Then   ' Month-Day-Year
    lngPos1 = InStr(1, Now(), strDateSeparator)
    If lngPos1 = 4 Then
        strMonthFormat = "mmm"
    End If
    strDateFormat = strMonthFormat & strDateSeparator & strDayFormat & strDateSeparator & strYearFormat
    
ElseIf lngDateFormat = 1 Then   ' Day-Month-Year
    lngPos1 = InStr(1, Now(), strDateSeparator)
    lngPos2 = InStr(lngPos1 + 1, Now(), strDateSeparator)
    If lngPos2 - lngPos1 = 4 Then
        strMonthFormat = "mmm"
    End If
    strDateFormat = strDayFormat & strDateSeparator & strMonthFormat & strDateSeparator & strYearFormat
    
Else    ' Year-Month-Day
    lngPos1 = InStr(1, Now(), strDateSeparator)
    lngPos2 = InStr(lngPos1 + 1, Now(), strDateSeparator)
    If lngPos2 - lngPos1 = 4 Then
        strMonthFormat = "mmm"
    End If
    strDateFormat = strYearFormat & strDateSeparator & strMonthFormat & strDateSeparator & strDayFormat
End If

MsgBox strDateFormat

EndLine:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(1, 1) = strDateFormat   

Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
If Err.Description <> "" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(1, 1) = Err.Description
End If
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Activate

End Sub



Function isSheetExists(wbk As Workbook, strSheetName As String) As Boolean
isSheetExists = False

For i = 1 To wbk.Sheets.Count
    If wbk.Sheets(i).Name = strSheetName Then
        isSheetExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
Function GetDateFormat() As String
    GetDateFormat = Application.International(17)
    Select Case Application.International(32)
        Case 0: GetDateFormat = "m" & GetDateFormat & "d" & GetDateFormat & "yy"
        Case 1: GetDateFormat = "d" & GetDateFormat & "m" & GetDateFormat & "yy"
        Case 2: GetDateFormat = "yy" & GetDateFormat & "m" & GetDateFormat & "d"
    End Select
    If Application.International(43) Then GetDateFormat = Replace(GetDateFormat, "yy", "yyyy")
    If Application.International(41) Then GetDateFormat = Replace(GetDateFormat, "m", "mm")
    If Application.International(42) Then GetDateFormat = Replace(GetDateFormat, "d", "dd")
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way:

```
if Application.International(xlMDY) then ...
```

True - month, day, year 
False - day, month, year

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840213%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: what about Year, Month, Day (like mine)?